# Se cierra la conexion de un WebSocket en Heroku automaticamente

Tags: javascript, heroku, websocket

Tengo un chat creado con websockets usando un codigo ya hecho por otro, este chat funciona bien en localhost.
Al inicio, lanzaba un error porque no era una conexion segura, eso lo arregle colocando wss en lugar de ws.

Ahora, ya no sale ese error sobre la conexion. Pero cuando entro a la pagina de Heroku donde esta implementado el chat me aparece una alerta que dice "Conexion Cerrada". Esta alerta aparece cuando se activa el evento onclose del websocket. Luego de pulsar aceptar, el chat no funciona pues el websocket esta cerrado.

**Lo que yo quiero saber es como evitar que la conexion se cierre. Si es que necesito configurar algo en Heroku o si necesito cambiar algo del codigo.**

El codigo lo saque de aqui:

Pagina para probar: http://oscaruhp.github.io/chatSocketAchex/

Repositorio: https://github.com/oscaruhp/chatSocketAchex

Unicamente he modificado cosas de los estilos y agregados algunos elementos más. Pero esta no es la razon por la que se cierra la conexion. Como dije, el chat funciona bien en localhost.

**Codigo que inicia la conexion con el websocket y donde aparece la alerta:**

```
function IniciarConexion() {
  conex = '{"setID":"' + Room + '","passwd":"' + pass + '"}';
  ws = new WebSocket("wss://achex.ca:4010");
  ws.onopen = function () { ws.send(conex); }
  ws.onmessage = function (Mensajes) {
    var MensajesObtenidos = Mensajes.data;
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(MensajesObtenidos);
    AgregarItem(obj);

    if (obj.sID != null) {


      if ($('#' + obj.sID).length == 0) {

        $('#listaOnline').append('<li class="list-group-item" id="' + obj.sID + '"><span class="label label-success">&#9679;</span> - ' + obj.Nombre + '</li>');

      }

    }

  }
  ws.onclose = function () {
    alert("Conexión cerrada");
  }
}
```

Seria la funcion más importante, lo demas son funciones para crear las partes del DOM del chat. De todos modos esta en el link que he pasado, de igual manera puedo editar esto y pasarlo por aca de ser necesario.

He tratado de buscar por el devcenter de Heroku, pero en la parte sobre conexiones con WebSockets no he encontrado algo útil con mi problema.
Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme o si no quiza si pueda decirme otra forma de implementar un chat en Heroku que si funcione.

Editado:

He estado viendo más de mi problema y veo que aparece un codigo de error **1006.** Que segun vi es un codigo anormal y sucede por un error en el lado del cliente o algo asi, no estoy seguro. Creo que esto ya seria parte de una pregunta diferente, pero supongo que eso causa el cierre pero no como solucionarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente, y tal y como se refleja en la [documentación de Heroku DevCenter](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/websockets#timeouts), la conexión se estaría cerrando automáticamente debido a una posible inactividad.

Te recomendaría probar a planificar un ping para mantener la conexión abierta, algo parecido a esto, a ver si te puede servir de ayuda (según la implementación que tengas):

```js
const wsLib = require('ws');

// Establecer la conexión a través de WebSocket con tu servidor Heroku
const ws = new Websocket('ws://your-server.herokuapp.com/');  // ws ó wss
const PING_TIME = 25;

// Función que hace un ping (el parámetro es un callback vacío)
const ping = () => ws.ping(() => {});

// Establecer la ejecución periódica del ping. Para cancelar, utilizar clearInterval
setInterval(ping, PING_TIME * 1000);
```

Comment: Implemente tu codigo, pero aun asi falla. Viendo un poco más mi problema, vi que me da un error con codigo 1006. Edite mi pregunta inicial para colocarlo, ¿deberia crear otra pregunta?.